# Why is my Google Scholar profile not in English language when I search my name in Google?

Tags: google-scholar

I read all comments for fixing my problems regarding my Google Scholar profile. When I search my name in Google, my Google Scholar profile appears in the Indonesian Language. I fixed the cookies, I changed the language to English from this link (https://scholar.google.com/scholar_settings?hl=en#1 ), I manually changed the URL, but as soon as I leave my Google Scholar profile and search for it on Google, the same problem still exists. It seems I never changed the language in my profile. I checked my account languages to make sure that there is no Indonesian language there.

Comment: This is not under your control.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but a typical Google Scholar profile link looks like: `https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=B7vSqZsAAAAJ`. The `hl=en` part specifies the language, and you can set this to any code from [this list](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp). For example, [Italian](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=it&user=B7vSqZsAAAAJ) or [Chinese](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=zh&user=B7vSqZsAAAAJ).

Answer (score 3):

**There is no language associated with a profile**. Anyone who searches for your profile from Google Scholar when logged in will see it in the language they have specified in their own settings. This only changes the language of the UI, and does not affect the content (publications, etc.) in your profile.

In addition to this, **Google's search results are personalized**. For some reason, Google's search algorithm seems to have decided that the Indonesian version of your profile is the most relevant to your account and location. This need not be the same version that appears in the search results when someone else, using a different account at a different location, searches for it, and there is no way for you to influence this.

So, there is no problem here that needs to be fixed, and **changing how the search results appear to you, even if possible, would not have any effect on how it appears to others**.

Answer (score 0):

If the software is written a certain way, the IP address of your ISP is typically used with a service that associates it with a geographic location.

The only way to work around this is to use a VPN service, which (when running) will take your requests locally from your machine and send them (in a secure way) to a machine in another country.  To the applications you are using (Google Scholar), this country's machine will seem to be the only one making the request.

[This is the first link about VPN setups I found with a Google search](https://pixelprivacy.com/vpn/change-ip-address/).  It's not a promotion that I benefit from; but, beware that it's nearly impossible to find information about these services that don't also advertise their services.  Before using any of them, do some comparative reviews, as they'll all guide you to their product.

Occasionally you can create an account, and sometimes the software will use the preferences of your account to configure your language.  From my lack of using Google Scholar heavily, I cannot state if Google did the programming to store and maintain the overridden location to language lookup with a logged in Google account clearly asking for a different language.  If they did implement this, it still doesn't mean you always get your desired language, as there can also be bugs in the overriding, or scenarios where you launched a search without logging in first.

Note that all of these are how you would look up your information.  What other people see when they look up your information is completely dependent on their IP address geolocation information and their account preferences.  You can't force your information to display in your chosen language for someone else; mostly because that's not how they wrote the software.  They wrote it to service the expected language of the requestor, not of the presentor.